# Is metaphor a type of analogy?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Some people told me that metaphor is a type of analogy. If so, is it too general if I consider a technique as an analogy at school when I have to find techniques and analyse them (provide names of the techniques, examples and effects)? Should I just consider an analogy as either a metaphor or simile or some other specific techniques (other types of analogy that I still don't know)?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Since they describe the same phenomenon, you should consider _analogy_ and _metaphor_ and _simile_ as terms for the same thing, used in different ways for different purposes by different people. None of these concepts are in any case well-defined or distinguishable, except artificially. The difference between [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) and metonymy is worth noticing, though.

Comment: In general, "analogy" is a rather sterile, mechanical term that can be applied to physics or literature or analog computing.  Usually when an analogy is used in this sense the "set up" context clearly explains that thing A is being used, by analogy, to provide the reader an understanding of certain features of thing B.  A "metaphor", on the other hand, is rarely handled this way.  Even in those cases (probably fewer than half) where the reader is given advance warning that a metaphor is being used, understanding how and why is left as a poetic mystery.  And a "simile" is "like" a metaphor.